# Mob death detection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently started working on a map and I encountered a problem when it comes to Mob death detection. I tried [this setup](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345984/how-do-i-detect-the-death-of-a-mob/365531#365531) but it just didn't work for me because I got really confused with it. So I'm asking if anyone knows how to do this?
I want to make something like a Mob Detection System. For example: the player kills a mob, the mob's death somehow sends a Redstone signal to a command block, which then teleports the player.

Comment: Rather than track mob death, why not track player mob kills?

Comment: What kind of mob, how many mobs, please give some more information

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I detect the death of a mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/345984/how-do-i-detect-the-death-of-a-mob)

Comment: "it just didn't work for me because I got really confused with it" is not a proper statement of your problem. What part of it didn't work? In what way? What have you tried yourself beyond that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type this command into the chat:

```
/scoreboard objectives add mobKilled minecraft.killed:minecraft.zombie
```

Then in a repeating always active command block put this command in it:

```
/tp @a[scores={mobKilled=1..}] *your location here*
```

Then in a chain, conditional, always active command block connected to the repeating one:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[scores={mobKilled=1..}] mobKilled 0
```

The first command creates a scoreboard which tracks zombie deaths,

Then the repeating command block teleports all players who have killed a zombie to your location,

Then the chain command block resets the players score
(The mob can be changed in the first command if you want, like this: minecraft.killed:minecraft.mobhere instead of zombie

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, I would appreciate it if you marked it as answer