# How to write a command that detects the death of the Wither?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I make a command detect the death of a wither (it has a name tag)

Comment: Hi Fmb, what have you tried so far?

Comment: There has got to be a "how to detect death of mob" question somewhere on our site, I just can't find it for Bedrock.

Comment: This is the closest question I can find for bedrock: [How do I make a specific scoreboard for mob kills in bedrock edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/369145/31508). For a more topical question in Java edition, see [How do I detect the death of a mob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/345984/31508)

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please see our [guide on asking Minecraft commands questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”. Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Answer (score 0):

To detect a death in Minecraft BE, use these commands (shown in the video below).

There are four (4) different command blocks that you need to add. Use these commands (with settings specified):

1. Repeat, Unconditional, Always Active
   (  `XP 1L @a[tag=!Dead,l=0]`  )
2. Chain, Unconditional, Always Active
   (  `tag @e[type=player,tag=!Dead] add Dead`  )
3. Repeat, Unconditional, Always Active
   (  `effect @a[l=0,tag=Dead] hunger 5 5`  )
4. Chain, Unconditional, Always Active
   (  `tag @e[tag=Dead,l=0] remove Dead`  )

(Replace the `type` with `minecraft:wither` and add it's name with `name="<NAME>"`):

Comment: Can you at least add to your post the command? This is nearly a link only answer at the moment.